# Complex JSON and looping over to update data

Tags: arrays, json, coldfusion

I have the following JSON code which I need to convert to structure to insert into the database

```
JSON


0
    Object { SGID=49,  SSID=9669,  SEQ=1,  more...}

GRADE
    ""

GRADEDESC
    null

SEQ
    1

SGID
    49

SSID
    9669

1
    Object { SGID=50,  SSID=9669,  SEQ=2,  more...}

GRADE
    ""

GRADEDESC
    null

SEQ
    2

SGID
    50

SSID
    9669

2
    Object { SGID=51,  SSID=9669,  SEQ=3,  more...}

3
    Object { SGID=52,  SSID=9669,  SEQ=4,  more...}

4
    Object { SGID=53,  SSID=9669,  SEQ=5,  more...}

5
    Object { SGID=54,  SSID=9669,  SEQ=6,  more...}

6
    Object { SGID=55,  SSID=9669,  SEQ=7,  more...}
```

For simple JSON to struct, I am doing like this the following is the code where I am getting the JSON object, and then I am converting them into the structure, but this time the JSON is complex, so need to know how to make an entry to the update table, I had actually tried the dump of the struct and I got

**Structures > Arrays[every element has 7 elements in form of structure ] >
Struct**

Here is the screen

[image]

```
<cfset var items= toString(getHttpRequestData().content) />
<cfset var Master = deserializeJSON(items) />
```

Trying like this but I am stuck

```
 <cfloop index="k" from="1" to="12">
    <cfquery>
        UPDATE table
        SET
          Gr = '#Trim(Evaluate("GR#k#"))#',
          desc = N'#Replace(Trim(Evaluate("Desc#k#")), "'", "''", "All")#'
        WHERE id = #k#
    </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

The above is what I tried and does not seems to the working thing, I am missing something I know and where and what that I am lost in

Comment: I don't know what that data is, but it's not JSON.

Comment: hmm, well whatever it is, i need to update the query by loop over

Comment: A larger screenshot of the cfdump would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a few things main things are wrong

1. The code is not working the array properly
2. The db column names are different from the data coming in
3. No `<cfqueryparam>`

---

```
<cfloop index="k" from="1" to="12">
   <cfquery>
    UPDATE table
        SET
          Gr = <cfqueryparam value="#gradeRecords[k].grade.trim()#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">,
          desc = <cfqueryparam value="#gradeRecords[k].gradedesc#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
        WHERE id = <cfqueryparam value="#k#" CFSQLType="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
    </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```